# Service not started in android 4.4.2

Tags: java, android

I wrote an application that has a service, the service starts as START_STICKY, on most devices the service is killed and restarted once in a while, on my nexus 5 with android 4.4.2 the service is killed and never restarted. why is that?

Answer (score 2):

There is an ongoing bug reported for this issue: http://goo.gl/8J4pon

Hope it is fixed soon.

Comment: Update: Android 4.4.3 versions: start_Sticky is working. I tested a couple of times it is working on my Nexus 5. I guess the bug has been fixed.

Comment: Is there a solution for this on 4.4.2?

Comment: I have alarm manager to start the service for 4.4.0, 4.4.1 and 4.4.2.